# Replace text in excerpt

Tags: excerpt, text, customization

I have a separate theme for my custom WP install that will be use for mobile users, in my case I need to change an html tag in all the excerpt instances but without altering the DB, I found this simple function that would be perfect but I can't get it to work, nothing's happening.

```
function replace_content_on_the_fly($text){
$replace = array(
    // 'words to find' => 'replace with this'
    '<p>' => '<div>',
    '</p>' => '</div>'
);
$text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
return $text;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'replace_content_on_the_fly');
```

I added the above code in my theme `function.php`. Why doesn’t it work?

Answer (score 1):

You code works where the function `the_excerpt` is used. It does not work when `get_the_excerpt` is used, which [does not apply the `the_excerpt` filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post-template.php#L260). It applies `get_the_excerpt` instead.

Using `get_the_excerpt` will cause the filter to apply to both the cases since [`the_excerpt()` uses `get_the_excerpt()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post-template.php#L248).

Automatically generated excerpt content is a different thing since it is created by [a filter on `get_the_excerpt`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L147) that [strips the markup](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2143).

Comment: In my `index.php` I have this `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` and the excerpt is not auto generated, so if I change the filter to `get_the_excerpt`  instead of `the_excerpt` that should work but I still see no changes.

Comment: Excerpts are generated when I try it. Have you tried using TwentyTwelve or TwentyThirteen?

Comment: Ok I don't need to generate the excerpt, I have custom ones already created, I was now trying to get it to work on `the_content` using the default themes but same thing, doesn't seem to work, I even tried to replace the word _sample_ with something else in a post instead of trying to alter an HTML tag but nothing is happening.

Comment: After reinstalling WP and reimporting the DB the function started working on my theme!